# Serialization Error When using WebService class as parameter to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting strange error when i run Service.svc file :
I have used one class ( from another Webservice ) as a parameter to the function.
If i comment that function in Interface , its working fine.

```
 Type cannot inherit from a type that is not marked with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute.  Consider marking the base type  with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute, or removing them from the derived type.
```

Could somebody help me regarding this.

thans in advance and
Sorry  for my bad english.

Comment: do you have access to the base type?

Comment: Yes, But the base type is not marked with  DataContractAttribute  or SerializableAttribute as those are from web service..

Comment: do you perhaps have a mix of web-services (which will have xml markers) and service-references (which will have dcs markers)? Also: it is a bad idea to mix types between different web-services, if that is what you are doing

Comment: I think No. I am consuming a webservice and expose one of the class (from web service) to WCF method getting the said error. Thanks for your reply on this.

Comment: could you please help me to sort out this issue

Comment: Perhaps edit the post and include more detail on the problem if you want an answer, its too general..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Marc is correct and perhaps there is a miscommunication.  He/I think that you are consuming a webservice and reusing a class from that same web service (which you likely generated code for) as a parameter in a different wcf web service which you are writing.

Essentially, the type which is generating the error likely does not have the DataContractAttribute which it requires.

Comment: So to be a little more clear.  I would not directly use the type from the web service you are consuming, instead you should write your own type which is likely to be fairly similar, and use that instead.

Comment: Yes You are correct. To add that point, we can use Object mapper to copy objects.